# CAPTCHA with Burpsuite or AppScan

Tags: burp-suite, captcha

I have an web application which uses login user password and captcha for login. Is there a way to perform vulnerability assessment using AppScan or Burpsuite tools to capture the CAPTCHA automatically and crawl and audit the application

Comment: Most sites use a testing account that does not trigger the CAPTCHA

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way to perform vulnerability assessment using AppScan or Burpsuite tools to capture the CAPTCHA automatically and crawl and audit the application**

No, there is no such thing as automatically capture CAPTCHA, yes, there are tensorflow stuff to make it happen but certainly not suitable for recaptcha version 3  from google and others too(you need a lot of data to train for specific type captchas and deal with false positives, after a while the juice is not worth the effort).

Here is what you may try, You can simply login to web app with captcha + credentials through burp proxy and when you have the session cookie set, you may proceed to do the vulnerability assessment scans with burp.

If your situation is where application logs you out after a while or with one wrong payload, hopefully macros can help you OR try using API version of application to get valid session cookies, after you have valid cookies, set the cookie and the procedure to crawl + scan remains the same.